# Term/word for low-volume, agressive, "shouty" speech

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What is a good word or phrase that describes someone speaking in a hostile, aggressive (even condescending) tone, with excaggerated facial features, **but** the volume of his/her voice is at a normal level (ie: all the traits of shouting in anger, but turning down the volume)? A good example of this is [A Few Good Men](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FnO3igOkOk&t=0m20s), where we see the attorney suddenly become very hostile, but his voice is somewhat restrained (until he starts shouting 2 seconds later).

The closest term I could find is "whisper shout", but I think that applies to when someone is trying to speak in a restrained voice (ie: lower pitch) so their voices carries a longer distance without being as obvious to others nearby.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not an exact fit, but I think ***[hiss](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hiss)*** comes close....

> 2:  to utter or whisper angrily or threateningly and with a hiss
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hiss)*</sub>